# Laravel 5.3 not logging

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, logging

I’ve inherited a Laravel 5.3 application that does not appear to be logging web processes or anything else on the server-side in my development environment. Here’s the things I’ve tried/confirmed.

- Set `APP_DEBUG = true`
- `storage/logs` exists and all users have read/write/execute permissions
- I’ve created an empty `laravel.log` file, thinking it needs to exist before it can be written to. I’ve also run the app without that file.

FWIW, this app is running in a vagrant instance and has debugger bar installed.

Any thoughts on what is going on here or something I can try to get logging started?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it hiding in the vagrant instance here: `/var/log/nginx`

That solved, I'd still be grateful for any insight or resource as to how or why that's configured. Knowing this and searching within the project and combing through the `Vagrantfile` still doesn't shed light on why it's being saved there rather than `storage/logs`.

Comment: What type of errors?  laravel.log is only for application errors.  Web server and most PHP errors would be in the web server logs.

Comment: I think that was my confusion, @Devon. I'm coming from a Rails world where you can monitor all the web server activity and DB queries in the Rails console, so I was expecting this with Laravel.

Comment: That's the case if you run artisan serve, but not if you run PHP through nginx.